# python input int only from input statement

Tags: python

I'm new to python and am trying to check if `startmiles` and `endmiles` are input as integer only and `gallons` are input as float. When I enter alpha the program crashes. Thank You

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import subprocess
import datetime 
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')

clear()

t = datetime.datetime.now()
from time import gmtime, strftime
strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X +0000", gmtime())
today = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y ")
print(today,'\n')

def main():
    startmiles = input("Enter Your Start Miles = ")
    endmiles = input("Enter Your Ending Miles = ")
    gallons = input("Enter Your Gallons = ")
    mpg = (int(endmiles) - int(startmiles)) / float(gallons)
    print("Miles Per Gallon =", round(mpg, 2))
    answer = input("\n Go Again Y or n ").lower()
    if answer == 'y': print('\n'), main()
    if answer != 'y': print('\n Thank You Goodbye')



if __name__=="__main__":
    main() # must be called from last line in program to load all the code
```

Comment: `when I enter alpha the program crashes` It would be much easier to help if you posted the exact error message, instead of vaguely telling us "the program crashes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your inputs to int/float as soon as they are entered, wrapped in a try/except block in a loop to catch exceptions and immediately prompt again for more input:

```
while True:
    try:
        startmiles = int(input("Enter Your Start Miles = "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('that is not an integer, please try again')
```

Or just wrap your final calculation in a try/except:

```
try:
    mpg = (int(endmiles) - int(startmiles)) / float(gallons)
except ValueError:
    print('some error message')
```

But this way you can't easily ask for more input, and you don't know exactly which value caused the error.

Comment: Thank You this fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x the input should result in an integer anyways, unless you use raw_input. It looks like your mpg variable is taking the integer of the endmiles anyways.

In Python 3.x

```
startmiles = int(input("Enter Your Start Miles = "))
```

It sounds like you're saying certain characters crash the program, which means you need to do some exception handling. See [this question response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for more detail, but you need to find a way to handle your exceptions instead of crashing. Here's an example below forcing proper entry of the variable.

```
while True:
    try:
        # Note: Python 2.x users should use raw_input, the equivalent of 3.x's input
        age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        #better try again... Return to the start of the loop
        continue
    else:
        #age was successfully parsed!
        #we're ready to exit the loop.
        break
    if age >= 18: 
        print("You are able to vote in the United States!")
    else:
        print("You are not able to vote in the United States.")
```